# How to display data inside the Uppy Dashboard Modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uppy

My clients want me to display the custom button and message inside the Uppy DashboardModal but I'm not able to display that. Anyone can please help me with this?

```
 <DashboardModal uppy={uppy}
            id={this.props.id || this.uploadModalId}
            inline
            disableStatusBar
            proudlyDisplayPoweredByUppy={false}
            showSelectedFiles={false}
            locale={{
              strings: {
                dropPaste: ''
              }
            }}
            plugins={['Dropbox', 'GoogleDrive']}
            width='100vw'
            height='177px'   
          >
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <Button>Hi</Button
          </DashboardModal>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that "dropPaste" in your example should instead be "dropPasteFiles" or "dropPasteFilders". Please see [here](https://uppy.io/docs/dashboard/#note-null) and search for "dropPasteFiles"

So to fix your code, try changing it to:

```
locale={{
          strings: {
            dropPasteFiles: 'My custom text: %{browse}'
          }
        }}
```